# Is it normal to say "chatte"? Are there any animals where you would always use the masculine version?

Tags: usage, genre, genre-biologique, zoologie

Someone who is not fluent pointed out to me that it is common to say "le chat" even for female cats, and that "la chatte" is considered vulgar, given that it is used to refer things besides cats.

I wanted to find out the validity of this assertion. Is it normal to use "le chat" for all cats? Is "la chatte" frowned upon, uncommon, or impolite?

Also, if any other animals come to mind that are relevant to this, where you would not use female, please mention them! Or is masculine generally used across the board?

Comment: Related: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/french-word-for-female-cat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il est tout à fait normal de parler d'une chatte quand le contexte est clair. Si je parle d'un animal familier que je connais je parle de la chatte ou du chat selon son sexe. 
J'ai une chatte chez moi, je dis :

> Où est passé la chatte ?

Je vois un animal dans mon jardin :

> C'est la chatte du voisin !

Je ne pense pas qu'il vienne à l'esprit de quiconque de penser à un autre sens du mot chatte dans des cas semblables.

Mais bien sûr comme il est tout de même difficile de reconnaître le sexe d'un chat de loin (en dehors des périodes de gestation), si je vois un chat inconnu dans mon jardin, je dirai plutôt :

> Tiens, un chat !

Ici je désigne l'objet « chat », l'animal générique.

Je pense qu'il en va ainsi pour tout animal dont le sexe n'est pas reconnaissable à l'oeil nu au non connaisseur. Tout est question de bon sens.

Je parlerai donc « du merle » qui picore sur ma pelouse, même si c'est une femelle (merlette ?) ou de « la pie » nichée sur l'arbre même si c'est un mâle (je ne connais pas de nom spécifique pour une pie mâle). Je sais en théorie que les oiseaux ont souvent des couleurs différentes selon le sexe mais je n'y connais rien et je ne dois pas être la seule.

Il est plus facile d'identifier le sexe d'un chien ou d'un lion donc je pense qu'on parlera plus spontanément d'une chienne ou d'une lionne qu'on voit pour la première fois.

Il est évident qu'un jeune homme bien élevé qui va chez une jeune fille pour la première fois, et même si sa nouvelle amie lui a déjà parlé de son animal familier, évitera de lui dire :

> Montre moi ta chatte.

Dans ce cas ce serait effectivement ambigu et pourrait être mal compris.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a matter of personal opinion and experience but I wouldn't say that using "la chatte" to designate a female cat is frowned upon or even less impolite (your interlocutor would need to learn the dictionary otherwise). "Ma chatte" is also used for sweetheart so I guess it wouldn't if "chatte" was vulgar regardless of the meaning intended by the locutor.

That said, I would say that the masculine is indeed more often used, in part to avoid uncomfortable situations sometimes and simply because some like me don't remember its gender.

As an aside to the story, a friend of mine named his chatte (female cat) "zizi" :-)

Comment: I think you mean "As an aside to the story" :)

Comment: @Aerovistae thanks! I actually meant "As a side story" but my voice recognition software screwed up. "As an aside to the story" sounds better :)

Comment: If you like speech recognition, try this chrome extension I wrote: www.handsfreechrome.com

Comment: @Aerovistae Thanks for the link, looks awesome! What speech recognition engine do you use? The JavaScript Web Speech API? Personally, I use a hands-free mouse (SmartNAV) in addition to Dragon NaturallySpeaking, so in the end, I don't need that any voice commands for browsing (also it's good to rest the voice a bit). In the [command list](http://www.handsfreechrome.com/commands.html), I have around half the commands of scrolling and none of clicking (-> hands-free mouse). I also have the navigation/tab/window/refresh commands. But that's very good to know, I'll keep in mind!

Answer (score -1):

I am an American, but spent my childhood (until age 13) in London, Ontario, Canada, which is just outside of Toronto. In Canada, french was part of our everyday curriculum starting in Grade Two. We then moved to the Sacramento, California area and took 4 years of high school French and four years of French in a University. My point in revealing all that is in every one of those French classes we only referred to cats in the masculine, “le chat” or, “un chat.” I didn’t even know there was a female possibility until 5 minutes ago. I’m flabbergasted:)

Comment: Do you know/use the name of a female dog in English?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/21844)

Comment: [_La Chatte métamorphosée en Femme_ (La Fontaine)](http://www.la-fontaine-ch-thierry.net/chatrans.htm), [_Femme et Chatte_ (Verlaine)](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Po%C3%A8mes_saturniens_(1866)/Femme_et_Chatte)... The entire Q&A manages to not disclose why using [_chatte_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chatte) could be challenging, it's just because it could also mean _pussy_ is all.