# What's the correct gender for pets?

Tags: genre, genre-biologique, zoologie

In English, the biological sex of a pet attaches to the pronoun used to refer to it. So I might say:

> What a beautiful cat! What's her name?

In French, does the gender attach to the sex of the pet, or the gender of the noun? In other words, for a female cat, would I say:

> Quel beau chat ! Comment s'appelle-t-**elle** ?

or:

> Quel beau chat ! Comment s'appelle-t-**il** ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Très souvent il existe un nom différent pour l'animal mâle et l'animal femelle, et dans ce cas le nom de l'animal est masculin pour le mâle et féminin pour la femelle :

Quelques exemples :

un chat - une chatte
un chien - une chienne
un oiseau - une oiselle
un cheval - une jument
un taureau - une vache
un coq - une poule
un merle - une merlette
un lapin - une lapine

Quand on ne connait pas encore le sexe de l'animal parce que ça ne se voit pas à l’œil nu on utilise le masculin par défaut.

> Comment s'appelle ton chat ?

Auquel on répond en utilisant le genre biologique :

> C'est une chatte, elle s'appelle Minette.

Quand le nom générique de l'animal n'existe qu'au masculin ou qu'au féminin, on utilisera plutôt le genre grammatical du nom.

> J'ai une souris blanche, elle s'appelle Auguste, c'est un mâle.
>
> J'ai un hamster noir, il s'appelle Louise, c'est une femelle.

Mais ça n'a rien de choquant d'utiliser le genre du sexe de l'animal :

> Mon canari s'appelle Kiki, elle a pondu deux œufs.

Si on utilise un adjectif, on l'accorde avec le nom immédiatement le plus proche :

> J'ai une nouvelle souris, c'est un mâle, il est gris.

---

Most of the time there's a different name for the male and the female animal.
When the name is the same for the male and the female, I assume most people will use the grammatical gender of the noun. When using an adjective with the noun then we'll agree the adjective with the closest noun.

Answer (score 4):

Dans la grande majorité des cas (au sens biologique), on ignore le genre biologique des animaux, et donc le genre du nom est utilisé. Exemples:

- Une araignée
- Une souris
- Un écureuil
- Une mouche
- Un ver

Pour les animaux domestiques, ou pour ceux où la différence est évidente à l'œil nu, il est possible qu'on connaisse le genre des animaux, dans ce cas, on utilise exclusivement le bon genre (y compris pour les petits). Exemples:

- Un chat / Une chatte / Un chaton
- Un cheval / Une jument / Un poulain
- Un lion / Une lionne / Un lionceau
- Un canard / Une canne / Un caneton

Si malgré tout on doit parler d'un de ces animaux sans en connaître le genre, alors le masculin est utilisé par défaut, et dans ce cas on reste dans le masculin. Il n'y a aucun sens à dire:

> Quel beau chat ! Comment s'appelle-t-elle ?

Il faut utiliser soit le masculin soit le féminin et ne pas changer d'avis, sinon ce n'est pas compréhensible pour un francophone natif.

> Quel beau chat ! Comment s'appelle-t-il ?
>   Quelle belle chatte ! Comment s'appelle-t-elle ?

Answer (score 3):

For animals and humans, French might have both genders available. You usually have the choice between using a sex-neutral noun (N) and a sex-specific one (M/F). The chosen neutral noun varies depending on the animal:

- cats: chat (N or M), chatte (F)
- cows: taureau (M), vache (N or F)
- sheep: bélier (M), brebis (F), mouton (N)
- gorillas: gorille (N or M/F)
- rats: rat (N)
- flies: mouche (N)

The grammatical gender usually follows the sex-specific pattern. Sex-neutrals have lexical gender (mouton M, rat M, mouche F). Some nouns for humans have misleading genders and give rise to agreement problems:

- sentinelle F (sentinel) usually refers to a male
- mannequin M (model) usually refers to a female

Answer (score 2):

In general, the female name for cat is also used (slang) for female genitals. So, most people use the male version of it all times. It's :
"Quel beau chat! Comment s'appelle-il?"

For dogs, the female name has also a negative connotation to it so it's best to use male version of it.
For the rest of animals, what difference does it make.

In english, if babies are called it in their early ages, i don't understand why someone would call a cat he or she.

Comment: When we know the cat is a she, then we use the feminine *elle* in French, same goes for a dog. This has [already been discussed on french.se](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/9737/358)

Comment: "In general, the female name for cat is also used (slang) for female genitals." Yes, even in English, to go "catting" is to go dating.