# In French, when referring to an animal is it proper to use il/elle based off of the animal's gender or the animals' species (dog)?

Tags: genre

For example, if you were describing a female dog would you use il or elle? Where I live people describe female dogs using "il" and I'm not sure if that's because they don't care about the dogs gender or because "dog" in French is a masculine noun, and so even a female dog would be referred to as "il".

Comment: Do the answers to this question answer yours ? [What's the correct gender for pets](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/9850/358) ?

Comment: The question also concern humans. Till 2000, many professions or roles like "auteur" (*author*), maire (*mayor*) or ministre (*"minister*) were masculine nouns.  The usage of "il" or "elle" may vary.  Example: `La sentinelle s'était endormie. Il(Elle) fut révéillé(e) par le sergent (*The sentinel had fallen asleep. The sergeant woke him up.*)` . If the context clearly establish that the sentinel is a man, both "il" and "elle" are acceptable. If the sex is unknown, then it's "elle", because "sentinelle" is feminine.

Comment: @Graffito For "*une sentinelle*" (or another more common example: "*une personne*"), I'd generally be surprised if "*il*" was used later on, unless there's additional information to clarify the gender (e.g. "*La sentinelle s'était endormie. C'etait un jeune cadet. Il [...]*"). I also don't think it's ever shocking to hear something about "*une personne*" that carries on with "*elle a ensuite fait ceci/cela", even if this person is male. That's also quite different from the feminisation of some professions and titles (generally meant to break the assumption that the person is male).

Comment: @bruno : we are at one on all points, i.e.  "if the context clearly establish that the sentinel is a man" == "unless there's additional information to clarify the gender". On the other case,(unknown gender), I wrote that *It's "elle", because "sentinelle" is feminine*.

Answer (score 3):

It's not correct to use "il". If the name is femimine the pronoun has to be "elle".

- La chienne a mal à la patte, *elle* boite de plus en plus et *elle* gémit.

In French it is not very  natural to say "un chien femelle". Here is for example what can be gathered from *[Histoire lexicographique ou Diction,naire Français Flamand](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Histoire_lexicographique_ou_le_dictionna/0AlKAAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22chien+femelle%22&pg=PA19&printsec=frontcover)* from 1846 (Jacob F.J. Heremans, ‎Philippe Olinger).

[image]

However, if this page of [Google examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chien%20femelle%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) shows many false positives, there are cases of use of "chien femelle".

*Example*

([La Chine: Journal de Pékin (1963-2008)](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Chine/htpHAwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22chien+femelle%22&pg=PT672&printsec=frontcover))  un chien femelle et un chien mâle, la femelle que l'on voit au bout du dessin remarque que le mâle est adorable, qu'elle est amoureuse de lui, et le chien mâle dit : « Elle est pas mal celle-là, mais elle n'a pas l'air très intelligente ...

Corresponding to this use you can use "il" because the term is masculine ("chien" is head word) and if the discussion is not concerned with the female characteristics of the animal, but you can also assume right away that it is a  female, a bitch, and use "elle".

Comment: +1, you can also use "il" when you don't know or care about the dog's gender.

Comment: I would add this is true for pets, but for example we don't do this for "une girafe", "un hippopotame", "une chouette", ...

Comment: Is it acceptable in all places to use "chienne" to talk of your female pet, even though it can mean bitch?

Comment: @aamart01 definitely  acceptable and correct.

Comment: @aamart01 in Québec we have a couple expressions, "avoir la chienne", or "c'est chien", (there may even be the more historical "fils de chienne") which are all pejorative, but not nearly as bad as the English "bitch". If, on the other hand, you say "c'est ma chienne" for "that's my dog", no negative connotation is involved.

Comment: @aamart01 in French, "biche" actually refers to a doe, and has a romantic cachet. "Biche des amours, gazelle pleine de grâce: Sois en tout temps enivré de ses charmes, Sans cesse épris de son amour." (Proverbes 5:19)

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use _bitch_ for a female dog in English, but you need to be careful that the context is very clear.  However, I've used _chienne_ more often than I've used _bitch_, even though I speak English much more often than French. (originally from Quebec, but I've lived in the US for >30 years)

Answer (score 3):

LPH answer is very detailed and accurate.

From experience, we tend to use il/elle depending on the animal gender. If one does not have this information, we tend to use il/elle based on the species gender.

I hope it makes sense.

EDIT: This is true for pet, as mentioned by @Flying_whale.

Comment: Could you give an example to clarify? For example, for a giraffe (une girafe), if you know the particular giraffe is a boy, then would you use "il" to refer to it in conversation, despite it being "une girafe" grammatically? I heard at least one French speaker say that for example, for "une chèvre" that he would naturally use elle to refer to that animal, even if it happens to be a male chèvre.

Comment: Technically, a male chèvre is a bouc ... But I understand what you are trying to say. In the case of a giraffe, I have to say that I would go for une girafe all the time but I never meet this. Therefore, my comment may be misleading. This has to work with common animals .. or pets.
EDIT: I have just seen Flying_whale's comment above and she is right. My remark is true for pets.

Comment: The comment above is a discrepancy I've noticed. Some people I've seen like to refer to animals by their species gender even if they know the animal is of the opposite gender, which I find quite confusing. If I am using an adjective (like vieux/vieille) to describe the animal in question, do I use the adjective based off of the animal's gender or the species gender?

Comment: I have never heard/read le vieux girafe for example. However, la vieille chienne and le vieux chat are definitely common use. Once again, now that I made up my mind, we use the animal's gender for pets and species gender for all other animals.
I do not have enough reputation to reply to your comment on LPH's answer, but yes, you can use chienne even though it means "bitch" and same for chatte while it means "pussy". In practice, I tend to add the surname of the dog after to avoid confusion.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you. Now what if I want to talk of a male giraffe. How could I specify he is male? Would I continue to say elle? Could I say "la girafe mâle" and then use il?

Comment: By "species gender" do you mean une girafe is a "female species" because the species is "la girafe"? For example, I see in Wikipedia, one can say "le girafon" or sometimes "le girafeau" but of course the species as a whole is referred to as "la girafe" ("the giraffe" in English, with no gender marker on the species itself in English, of course).

Comment: I believe I've heard girafon refer to young/baby giraffes but I've never heard of le girafeau. If I specifically wanted to talk of a male giraffe (or any male animal of a female specifies which does not have another name), would it be too odd sounding to refer to it as le?

Comment: I have never heard of le girafeau either, only girafon which is the young giraffe. From the dictionnary, it seems that girafeau meens the same thing. Therefore, there is no masculine of a giraffe.. And this seems odd because I do not consider it masculine either. Saying la girafe mâle is the way that sounds the least weird to me. Saying le girafe feels wrong. However, keep in mind that I talk from a practical POV as a native speaker. It could be that someone into animals study could have a different answer.

Comment: So after saying "la giraffe mâle" I could use il? Or must I continue to use elle?

Comment: I would use il.

An example: "La girafe mâle rejoint son lieu de prédilection pour y retrouver ses petits. **Il** apporte le soutien nécessaire à la girafe pour accompagner les premiers pas effectués par les girafons" Sorry, I am not so inspired.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by inspired, but thank you so much. I would upvote you but unfortunately I am new to this platform and am not allowed to yet. But you have been a big help.

Comment: Inspired to write a short story I meant :). I am also new here, but thanks it was actually nice to discuss about it from my side as well, I learned something!

Comment: In addition to all this, a number of native French speakers often have to be corrected regarding similar species that are gendered differently:  la grenouille n'est pas la femelle du crapaud et la chouette n'est pas la femelle du hibou.

Comment: That is correct Bruno

Answer (score 2):

We use the gender of the noun used to name the animal if its gender is unknown or irrelevant. This noun gender is often masculine but can be feminine too.

- *Un chien*, *il*
- *Un cheval*, *il*
- *Une souris*, *elle*
- *Une belette*, *elle*

If the animal gender is known/relevant and a form matching it exists, it will be used:

- *Une chienne*, *elle*
- *Une jument*, *elle*

If the noun only has a single gender, we will use it and specify the actual gender if needed:

- *Une souris mâle*, *elle*
- *Une araignée femelle*, *elle*
- *Une girafe mâle* (then the pronoun used would often be *elle* unless we formally switch to the masculine by saying *le mâle*)
- *Une belette mâle*, *elle*
- *Un crabe femelle*, *il* (or *une femelle crabe*, *elle*)

Sometimes, even if the feminine noun exists, the masculine might also be used:

- *Un éléphant femelle*, *il* or *elle* = *une éléphante*, *elle*