# In French, when referring to an animal would you use il/elle based off of the animal's gender or the animals' species (like a dog)?

Tags: grammaire

For example, if you were describing a female dog would you use il or elle? Where I live people describe female dogs using "il" and I'm not sure if that's because they don't care about the dogs gender or because "dog" in French is a masculine noun, and so even a female dog would be referred to as "il".

Comment: Welcome; I'll send this question over to French.SE, where it'll find a community with the relevant knowledge.  Here, we're interested in language learning techniques.

Comment: Oops!  Sorry, I just noticed this was already posted [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52996/22749).  Please close this one (I shouldn't have migrated it).

Answer (score 0):

Il/elle or the article le/la refer to the noun gender, that is *le chien* may refer to a female dog, as long as we do not need to be specific about its gender. If we do want to be specific, we use an appropriate feminine noun - *la chienne*.

For some species the names of species, male and female might be completely different, like *le mouton* is *le belier* when talking about an adult male, et *la brebis* for an adult female et *l'agneau* when referring to a young animal.